# How do you use PyObjC to turn off and on the wireless interfaces of a Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, wireless, pyobjc, corewlan

How do you use PyObjC to turn off and on the wireless interfaces of a Mac? My research to date has lead me to the Cocoa Framework and PyObjC. On the Mac Developer website I found an example of a wireless interface management application demonstrating how to use the Cocoa Framework to toggle on and off the wireless interfaces of a Mac [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html). This example indicates that the CWInterface under  the CoreWLAN Framework is necessary to accomplish the task of turning off and on the wireless interface of a Mac. However, PyObjC doesn't seem to include the CoreWLAN Framework from Cocoa in its wrapper [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc-framework-Cocoa/2.3) . Any thoughts on how to accomplish this task? Could I implement my own PyObjc objects to call the CoreWLAN Framework, and if so what would be a good resource on how to do this? Thanks for your time! Anything helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can load the framework manually using:

```
import objc
objc.loadBundle('CoreWLAN', 
       bundle_path='/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework', 
       module_globals=globals())
```

The classes in the framework are now available in the module globals dictionary.

Get the wireless interface with:

```
iface = CWInterface.interface()
```

You can then turn the power on or of with:

```
iface.setPower_error_(True, None)
```

or

```
iface.setPower_error_(False, None)
```

P.S. I'll add this framework in a future release, one reason it is not available at the moment is that I didn't know this is a public framework.