# Python scan for WiFi

Tags: python, wifi, python-3.5, scapy, sniffer

I was searching for a program that can scan for WiFi networks and print all of the SSIDs. I tried with scapy but I failed. I am using the pyCharm editor.

I tried this code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.dot11 import Dot11

def packet_handler(pkt):        
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == 2:        
        print(pkt.show())
scapy.sniff(iface="mon0", prn=packet_handler)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). As currently you should add a description of the problem this code is giving you (and full stack trace if appropriate) to your question

Comment: What was the result of your code?

Comment: For Mac OS: [Is there any way to access OS X wi-fi data using Python? (Signal strength, for example)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15169022/2745495)

Answer (score 11):

try `pip install wifi` then for scanning use

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
Cell.all('wlan0')
```

This returns a list of Cell objects. Under the hood, this calls iwlist scan and parses the unfriendly output. Each cell object should have the following attributes: ssid, signal, quality and more.
and for connecting use

```
cell = Cell.all('wlan0')[0]
scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'home', cell, passkey)
scheme.save()
scheme.activate()

scheme = Scheme.find('wlan0', 'home')
scheme.activate()
```

for more info goto https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Just a quick note - This python library works only on Linux systems

Comment: @NikhilBaliga so what do the rest of us do?

Comment: You could create a boot drive and install a flavor of linux, otherwise you will have to play around with the pyobjc lib to bridge the gap and try and access ios' airport https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/

Comment: please note that this library/project is no longer maintained by the developer :(

Comment: `wifi` module  not support Windows?