# Network channel Python

Tags: python, networking, wifi

Hi guys I'm working on a network project as I'm a beginner i hope you can help me: 
I'd like to retrieve the channel my network is on using python like netsurveyor is giving a graph showing the channel our network is using I'd like to know how in python I can get the same infos. I've linked a screnshot of netsurveyor to show more ecxplicitly what I'm trying to do.
[netsurveyor example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W22qh.png)

Comment: try look at this for the wifi package to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679421/python-scan-for-wifi

Comment: I have no experience with this package in particular, but it seems to be your best bet.

Comment: netsurveyor is a 802.11 monitoring tool, you will need to use something that can sniff 802.11 packets, like impacket or scapy. there are several github projects that have a simple implementation of it, i haven't used it but here's one that is well documented you can start from: https://github.com/rahilsharma/Scapy-wireless-scanner/blob/master/wireless_scanner.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to retrieve the informations needed

```
import subprocess
    available = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show network mode=bssid',stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
```

this command line give you the information needed : the output is like this:

> SSID 1 : Rezalitchderk
>       Network type            : Infrastructure
>       Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
>       Encryption              : CCMP 
>       BSSID 1                 : 62:f1:89:7c:71:d1
>            Signal             : 91%
>            Radio type         : 802.11n
>            Channel            : 11 
>            Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
>            Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
>
> SSID 2 : HUAWEI Mate 10 lite
>       Network type            : Infrastructure
>       Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
>       Encryption              : CCMP 
>       BSSID 1                 : 1c:15:1f:3f:87:f9
>            Signal             : 82%
>            Radio type         : 802.11n
>            Channel            : 11 
>            Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
>            Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54